# Как подружить pug и BrowserSync?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, pug

1. index.pug преобразовался в index.html
2. BrowserSync следил за изменениями index.html и показывал изменения в браузере без перезагрузки страницы
3. Код взят отсюда https://github.com/morphIsmail/gulp_build_2

```js
//Подключаем галп
const gulp = require('gulp');
//Объединение файлов
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
//Добавление префиксов
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
//Оптимизация стилей
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
//Оптимизация скриптов
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
//Удаление файлов
const del = require('del');
//Синхронизация с браузером
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
//Для препроцессоров стилей
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
//Sass препроцессор
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
//Less препроцессор
const less = require('gulp-less');
//Stylus препроцессор
const stylus = require('gulp-stylus');
// сжатие изображений
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
// подключаем html препроцессор puge
const pug = require('gulp-pug');
 
//Порядок подключения файлов со стилями
const styleFiles = [
   './app/css/main.scss',
   './app/css/color.sass'
]
//Порядок подключения js файлов
const scriptFiles = [
   './app/js/lib.js',
   './app/js/main.js'
]



//Таск для обработки стилей
gulp.task('styles', () => {
   //Шаблон для поиска файлов CSS
   //Всей файлы по шаблону './src/css/**/*.css'
   return gulp.src(styleFiles)
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      //Указать stylus() , sass() или less()
      .pipe(sass())
      //Объединение файлов в один
      .pipe(concat('style.css'))
      //Добавить префиксы
      .pipe(autoprefixer({
         // browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
         cascade: false
      }))
      //Минификация CSS
      .pipe(cleanCSS({
         level: 2
      }))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
      //Выходная папка для стилей
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

//Таск для обработки скриптов
gulp.task('scripts', () => {
   //Шаблон для поиска файлов JS
   //Всей файлы по шаблону './src/js/**/*.js'
   return gulp.src(scriptFiles)
      //Объединение файлов в один
      .pipe(concat('script.js'))
      //Минификация JS
      .pipe(uglify({
         toplevel: true
      }))
      //Выходная папка для скриптов
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

//Таск для очистки папки build
gulp.task('del', () => {
   return del(['dist/*'])
});

gulp.task('img-compress', () =>{
   return gulp.src('./app/img/**')
   .pipe(imagemin({
      progressive: true
   }))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/img/'))
});

//Таск для отслеживания изменений в файлах
gulp.task('watch', () => {
   browserSync.init({
      server: {
         baseDir: "./"
      }
   });
   // наблюдатель, который будет отслеживать изменения всех pug-файлов и обновлять транспилированный код:
   
   gulp.watch('./app/img/**', gulp.series('img-compress'))
   //Следить за файлами со стилями с нужным расширением
   gulp.watch('./app/css/**/*.sass', gulp.series('styles'))
   //Следить за JS файлами
   gulp.watch('./app/js/**/*.js', gulp.series('scripts'))
   //При изменении HTML запустить синхронизацию
   gulp.watch("./*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});


//Таск по умолчанию, Запускает del, styles, scripts и watch
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('del', gulp.parallel('styles', 'scripts', 'img-compress', 'pug'), 'watch'));
```

Comment: @MaximLensky только pug (index.pug) я смог запустить проблема в том что приходится каждый раз прописывать преобразование в index.html и потом ручками обновлять страницу; хочу чтобы gulp (автоматически) index.pug преобразовывал в index.html и это автоматически обновлялось

Comment: @MaximLensky на почту отправил сообщение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собственно сам gulpfile.js остальное скинул архивом ...

[Ссылка на архив в DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7b6ys3532ak6tg0/pug.zip)

Проверено: слежение за `scss`, `pug` при `live reload`

С начала инициировать gulp:  `npm install`

Запуск в cmd:  `gulp`

**Всё**

```js
const gulp = require('gulp')
const sass = require('gulp-sass')
const pug = require('gulp-pug')
const browsersync = require('browser-sync').create()

gulp.task('sass',  () => {
 return gulp.src('dev/scss/**/*.scss').pipe(sass({outputStyle:  'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError)).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
})

gulp.task('pug', () => {
 return gulp.src('dev/**/*.pug').pipe(pug({pretty: true})).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
})

gulp.task('default', () => {
 gulp.watch('dev/**/*.pug', gulp.series('pug'))
 gulp.watch('dev/scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'))
 gulp.watch('dist/**/*.html', browsersync.reload)
 browsersync.init({
  server:  {
    baseDir: './dist'
  }
 })
})
```